# TypeError: store.getState is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I'm new in react in action I want to access store data so that I can send it to the server, I'm trying to access store in my action like this
 `stote.getState().someKey`. But geeting the above mentioned error

My Action:

```
 export default function (userInfo){
  return function (dispatch, store){
   console.log(store.getState().someKey) //TypeError: store.getState is not a function
   someFunction(userInfo).then( function (response){
    dispatch(fetched(response))
     });
  dispatch(isFetching())
  }
}
```

my configureStore is like this.

```
import allReducers from '../reducers';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import {ENABLE_LOGGER} from '../config/config';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import loadingBarMiddleware from './loadingbar';

function configureStore(){
 let initialState ={}
  if(ENABLE_LOGGER){
    var store = createStore(allReducers, initialState,
     applyMiddleware(thunk, logger, loadingBarMiddleware())
  );
}
 else{
   var store = createStore(allReducers,
     applyMiddleware(thunk, loadingBarMiddleware())
   );
  }
 return store;
 }
export default configureStore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your thunk action, the second parameter isn't the store itself but rather directly the function getState. So it should look like hits:

```
export default function (userInfo){
  return function (dispatch, getState){
    console.log(getState().someKey)
    someFunction(userInfo).then(function (response){
      dispatch(fetched(response))
    });
    dispatch(isFetching())
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I pass store itself in my action ??

Comment: From what I could see, if someone really needs to access the instance of the store, they will create a module that exports instance of the store and then import it in other modules (e.g. with your action). Since you have access to both dispatch and state, what use case do you have for accessing the store itself?

Comment: as such there is no user case but if I can access getState why can't I access directly store .

Comment: Probably to limit the API area, make it possible to do just what's needed, and not more.

Comment: One more thought. There is another way you could pass store to your thunks. Thunk lib supports the withExtraArgument factory. You can pass a "getStore" fn there. https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#injecting-a-custom-argument